# Improper limits

Tags: calculus

Find $\lim_{x\rightarrow -1^-} \frac{5x^2+2x-1}{x^2-3x-4}$

Let us first consider the left-hand limit.

If $x$ tends to $-1$ on the left-hand side, then the numerator of the of the fraction $\frac{5x^2+2x-1}{{ x^2-3x-4}}$ tends to $2$, and the denominator tends to 0. We sketch the graph of the function of the quadratic function $y={ x^2-3x-4}$.

[image]

From the sketch, we read that if $x\rightarrow -1^-$, then $\left( x^2-3x-4 \right) \rightarrow 0^+$, so ${ \frac{1}{x^2-3x-4}\rightarrow +\infty }$

$\lim_{x\rightarrow -1^-} \frac{5x^2+2x-1}{x^2-3x-4}=\lim_{x\rightarrow -1^-} \left[ \left( 5x^2+2x-1 \right) \cdot \frac{1}{x^2-3x-4} \right] =\left[ 2\cdot \infty \right] =+\infty $

because:

$\lim_{x\rightarrow -1^-} \left( 5x^2+2x-1 \right) =2\\\lim_{x\rightarrow -1^-} \frac{1}{x^2-3x-4}=-\infty $

I don’t understand why?
${ \frac{1}{x^2-3x-4}\rightarrow +\infty }$

Comment: Do you understand why $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{1}{x}=+\infty$ and why $\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{1}{x}=-\infty$?

Answer (score 5):

Imagine you are dividing $1$ by a number very small (but positive), for example $0,1$, then $\frac{1}{0,1}=10$. What if we divide it by a smaller number? $\frac{1}{0,000001}=1000000$. We can note that the closer it gets to zero, the larger the result. This is a very informal approach, but it's an intuitive way to note that "when the denominator become smaller and the numerator is constant, the  the result of the division gets bigger".
Why $+  \infty$ and not $-  \infty$? Because the numerator is positive, and the denominator is very small, but still positive, because $x$ tends to $-1$ from the left, so intuitively it's like $-1,01$ , $-1,00001$ and so on, so $x^2-3x-4>0$

Answer (score 1):

As $x\to(-1)^-$, ${ \frac{1}{x^2-3x-4}\rightarrow +\infty }$ as you first explained well, not $-\infty$ as you claimed in your penultimate line.